# What is the nth term of this recursive sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is my function:

f(x)=f(x-1)*100+1

I am curious to know whether this can be expressed as a sequence.

Comment: You mean you want to know what is $f(n)$?  OK, what is $f(0)$?

Comment: If it is a function from the reals to the reals, where $x$ can be any real number, then it wouldn't be expressable as a "sequence" per se... but if it were a function from the naturals to the reals, absolutely it can be... after all, that is the definition of a sequence to begin with.

Comment: If you are asking what the closed form is, this is a linear-nonhomogenous recurrence relation.  Look that up on wikipedia or elsewhere on the site, but suffice to say that it will be of the form $f(n)=c\cdot 100^n + d$ where $c$ and $d$ are constants that can be solved for based on initial conditions.

Comment: Let $f(x)=100^x g(x)$ then the relation reduces to $g(x)=g(x-1)+ 1 / 100^{x}\,$ which telescopes.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$f(n + 3) = 100f(n + 2) +1 = 100(100f(n + 1) + 1) + 1 $$ $$= 100(100(100f(n) + 1) + 1) + 1= 100^3f(n) + \sum_{k = 0}^2 100^k.$$
Do you see where this is going? Once you get this, you can start with $f(0)$ and then compute $f(n) = f(n + 0)$ from the relation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-homogeneous linear difference equation.

We shall solve the homogeneous equation first, then find a particular solution and finally add them to form the general solution.

Subtracting
$$f(n+1)=100f(n)+1$$
from
$$f(n+2)=100f(n+1)+1$$

we obtain the second-order homogeneous equation
$$f(n+2)-f(n+1)=100f(n+1)-100f(n)$$

or 
$$f(n+2)-101f(n+1)+100f(n)=0$$

The roots of the characteristic polynomial

$$\lambda^2-101\lambda+100$$

are

$$\lambda_1=1$$
and
$$\lambda_2=100$$

Therefore the homogeneous solution is

$$f(n)=C\lambda_1^n+D\lambda_2^n=C+D100^n$$

As a particular solution, let us consider $f(n)$ to be a constant 
$c$

and insert into 
$$f(n+1)=100f(n)+1,$$

so
$$c=100c+1$$

and

$$c=-\frac{1}{99}$$

Now $C$ and $D$ in the homogeneous solution are found using the initial conditions that $f(n)=f(0)$ when $n=0$ and $f(n)=100f(0)+1$ when $n=1$.

Finally, the complete solution is

> $$f(n)=\dfrac{\left(99f(0)+1\right)100^n-1}{99}$$

(which may be obtained faster [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(n)%3D100f(n-1)%2B1;+f(0)%3Dk))

Comment: Wanted to let you know your answer was in the Low Quality review queue,you could consider adding more info like how did you derive this formula.

Comment: @kingW3 Done, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = g(x) + C$

$g(x) +C = 100g(x-1) +100C + 1$

Let $C =-\frac{1}{99}$

$g(x) = g(0) * 100^x$

$f(x) = (f(0) + \frac{1}{99}) * 100^x - \frac{1}{99}$